In robotframework selenium commands are not recognized eventhough i imported selenium libraries correctly
Am writing by first script in robot framework .  see below
*** Settings ***
Library  SeleniumLibrary
*** Variables *** 
${URL}    https://example.com/contact  # Replace with your actualURL
${BROWSER}    chrome
${MESSAGE}   Hello, this is a test message!
*** Test Cases ***
Send A Message
 Open Browser    ${URL}    ${BROWSER}
`
But i see redline under command open browser .when i mouse hover i see keyword definitions are not found ..
i already installed robotframework_seleniumlibrary via pip and inside Pycharm i added selenium library as well.
